# Is it possible to detect empty request?

Tags: php, python, google-app-engine, query-string

Is it possible to *see* if the user requests "example.com/mypage/?" or "example.com/mypage/"  ?

I would like to serve  different content if the query string is symbol "?" is present in the request. Please note that there is no name or value (e.g. ?name=value) , just the request symbol "?". A solution in python would be excellent but php is acceptable too.

Comment: I would think that this is a bad practice. question mark or not, the URLs point to the same resource.

Comment: Btw. I'm not sure if this is possible with python, since this affects the url of the php script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you can check if the `REQUEST_URI` ends in a `?`. There are three different cases that might be of use to you:

```
if('?' === substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], -1)){
    // Empty query string with '?'
}else if(false === strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?')){
    // No ? at all
}else{
    // Some query string exists (check $_GET)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

checking the last character

```
if ('?' === substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], -1))
```

Answer (score -1):

Take the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and check if there is any question mark in it.

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "?") >= 0) {
    //Question mark found
}
```

Comment: That would show whether there are parameters or not. OP is looking for a scenario with no parameters, only the question mark.

Comment: @cillosis But you get the whole call string after web server root, including the ?. If you call the url with only the ?, it'll still display /file.php?. You just need to check if there's a question mark in it. Also, check other answers, I'm not alone with this solution.